# Autoplay not working (SlidesJS)

Tags: jquery, slidesjs

I am using slides.js for one of my projects; however, the autoplay feature is not working properly.

Here is what I am doing:

```
$('#slides').slides({
    width: 600,
    height: 120,
    generateNextPrev: false,
    pagination: false,
    play: 1000
});
```

The documentation http://slidesjs.com/ says that by giving a positive number to `play`, autoplay should work. Can someone help?

Comment: Did u put the script inside $(function(){ }) ?

Comment: Just tested the script its working....check in firebug if there is any error

Comment: try run this code while on the page in firebug console... what happens?

Comment: which browser r u using?

Comment: putting the script inside function does not help

Comment: @Traveling_Monk I tried to run this code in the console and it did not give any error

Comment: did it do anything, like start running? if not then your script is wrong,,,

Comment: can yo uspecify what exactly is "not working" ? do the slides show up ?

Comment: @ObmerkNinenine yes the slides show up they work fine till I click on the previous and the next button but autoplay does not work and I am not able to get the images of previous next and pagination

Comment: do you have a direct link to the page with the problem ?

Comment: @ObmerkNinenine no I have not uploaded it yet, but I think the instructions given on slidesjs.com and the github link are not same

Comment: the problem is probably not in the instructions.. nor in your implementation - probably more of a syntax, css, or js conflict. without a complete code it is much harder to check. the code you have posted works for me as is ..

Comment: I have found a workaround for this which is working for me and posted it as my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it works this is something which is not given in the documentation :-

$(function(){

```
    $('.slides').slides({
        width: 600,
        height: 120,
        pagination: false,
        previous: false
    });

    $('.slides').slides("play");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been answered, but the function is actually .slidesjs NOT .slides

Answer (score 1):

For SlidesJS-3 you can use the following to trigger autoplay :

```
$(".slides").slidesjs({
        width: 768,
        height: 158,
        play: {
            auto: true
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

check the scripts loaded are not if yes then that should be in sequence like

1. script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
2. script src="slides.js"

Comment: scripts are loaded and it is in the order which you have mentioned, also other part of slides.js are working it is only the autoplay portion which is not working

Comment: all you need to do is set the portion try this                    $(function(){
      $("#slides").slides({
        preload: true,
        preloadImage: '/img/loading.gif',
        play: 5000,
        pause: 2500,
        hoverPause: true
      });
    });